# UniqueElement Counter Java

Tags: java, arrays

I just started a Java Data Structures summer class.  One of the problems assigned is instead of counting all the elements in the array, I am to find each unique element.

```
numUnique(new double[] { 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 33, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 55, 55, 66, 77, 88, 88 })==8

numUnique(new double[] { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88})==8
```

In the first example above 11 is listed 4 times, 22 once, 33 once, 44 5 times, 66 once, 77 once, and 88 twice.  there are 17 elements in the array but there are only 8 different numbers.  the two examples give the same output of 8 and thats what number I'm supposed to find.

Comment: There are so many ways to answer this.  Can you tell us what you have tried so far, or which approach you are expected to take?

Comment: all i have is the function that counts up all the elements in the array. i don't know how to post the code in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice easy way to do this in Java 8 without any intermediate collections:

```
List<Double> unique = Arrays.stream(array).distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or replace the collector with `count()` if you just want the number of unique elements.

Comment: This implementation only solves the problem of how many unique digits and not what are the unique digits thou

Answer (score 1):

Two straightforward ways to do this are adding the array to a set (which will remove duplicates by definition), or adding each number to a hashmap using the number as key.

Using a set:

```
double[] input = new double[] {11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 33, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 55, 55, 66, 77, 88, 88};
Set<Double> set = new HashSet<Double>(Arrays.asList(input));
System.out.println("There were " + set.size() + " unique numbers in the set.");
```

Using a map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i=0; i < double.length; ++i) {
    map.put(i, null);
}
System.out.println("There were " + map.keySet.size() + " unique numbers in the set.");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way for tracking unique items in Java is to use the HashMap implementation.

The API you will need are: containsKey() and put(). Have read at the API documentation below.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Example implementation:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] value1 = new double[] { 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 33, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 55, 55, 66, 77, 88, 88 };
        Map<Double, Integer> numberTracker = new HashMap<>();

        for(Double value : value1) {
            if (!numberTracker.containsKey(value)) {
                numberTracker.put(value, /*dummy value=*/1);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Double,Integer> entry : numberTracker.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: As you have got a double array therefore the output is going to be something in double data type. That is, it will be something like;
[ 33.0, 66.0, 77.0, 11.0... ]

You can solve the double type problem by either changing your array to be on Integer type or find a way to convert your double value into integer.

As this is supposed to be an assignment question, I'll leave the last bit to you.